# How do I retrieve timedate from the database and display in template?

Tags: python, database, django

I'm a complete Python and Django noob so any help is appreciated. This is what my model looks like:

```
class Matches(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    court = models.ForeignKey(Courts)

class Participants(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    match = models.ForeignKey(Matches)
    userid = models.ForeignKey(User)
    games_won = models.IntegerField()
```

This is what my view looks like:

```
def index(request):
    latest_matches_list = Matches.objects.all()[:5]
    return render_to_response('squash/index.html', {'latest_matches_list': latest_matches_list})
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

And my template:

```
{% if latest_matches_list %}
    {% for matches in latest_matches_list %}
        {{ match.id }}
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <p>No matches are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Two questions:

When I do `Matches.objects.all()` in the shell console it returns: `[<Matches: Matches object>]`. Why doesn't it print out the id and date?

In the template file I'm initially trying to test printing out the id of `Matches` but it doesn't seem to be working. What variable do I need for `{{ match.id }}`. The goal is to print out the following per match:

```
[matchid]    [date]    [time]     [player1_wins]  [player2_wins]
1            1-1-2011  20:00      6            8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: how would it know to print id and date out of all fields you might have?

You can define what your object returns when printed by defining `__unicode__`
[http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.**unicode**](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.__unicode__)

```
# ... model class

def __unicode__(self):
    return "%s %s" % (self.id, self.date)
```

2: In your template, you iterate over `latest_matches_list` with the variable `matches` yet you use `{{ match.id }}` which isn't defined. Use `{{ matches.id }}`.

```
{% for matches in latest_matches_list %}
    {{ match.id }} <!-- not defined -->
    {{ matches.id }} <!-- this is your variable -->
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks! So if I understand correctly, you're actually converting the integer into a string (unicode), right? Aren't integers stored as "unicode"?

Comment: Also, I put in {{ matches.date }} and got the output to work. However I want to format it now. I know there is formatting here: http://bit.ly/gVYXsL. So I tried {{ matches.date|"D d M Y" }} and get an error.

Comment: I'm using python's awesome string formatting. `%s`: convert to string via objects __str__ method http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations. This actually isn't a unicode string but it could be :)

Comment: Look at the example in the link you provided. Filter syntax is `{{ object | filter: "arguments" }}`  : )